# Remount Arch Linux installation CD to download some additional packages

Tags: arch-linux, mount, software-installation, live-usb, livecd

According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128538/connect-to-wifi-on-arch-linux) I can:

> Start the livedisk again, remount your drives archroot into your root
>   partition and then install the packages you need and everything should
>   work.

However, I cannot find any information on how to do it.

Could you please explain me what I should do to remount the installation CD and be able to download packages I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to other answers I was able to find this thread: [What's the proper way to prepare chroot to recover a broken Linux installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation).

As every step is extensively explained in the provided thread on SuperUser I will only provide a very simple solution to what I was trying to achieve.

This approach is a great way to recover or change certain files from your Arch if for example:

- the system is automatically turning off a few seconds after logging in and you want to remove those bad packages and config files.
- you want to run `sudo pacman -S iw wireless_tools network-tools dialog` to get your wifi working after installing Arch.

Here are the steps:

1. Use a LiveCD which has the same architecture as the system you want to chroot into.
2. If you need a network connection its time to set it up. You can use the  `wifi-menu` for example.
3. Now you'll have to enter these commands:

   ```
   cd /
   # I had to change ext3 to ext4. 
   # Depends on the filesystem one used during installation.
   mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt 
   mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
   mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
   mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   mount -t ext2 /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
   chroot /mnt /bin/bash
   ```
4. Now you are are in a shell and you can do what you want to do.
5. Cleaning up.

   ```
   exit
   umount /mnt/boot # if you mounted this or any other separate partitions
   umount /mnt/{proc,sys,dev}
   umount /mnt
   ```
6. The end.

   ```
   reboot
   ```

I strongly advise you to look at [the original answer at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation) and at [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111406/install-drivers-offline-arch-linux) which might be handy as well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! Now, if you also happen to remember to come back and accept this answer as soon as the waiting period is over, you'll get the Most Conscientious User award ;P

Comment: @terdon I can't wait to get my award :)

Comment: We can `reboot` without manually `umount`ing what was mounted, can't we? A shutdown automatically umounts everything, doesn't it?

Comment: @Al.G. I don't know so I am super careful.

Comment: According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/shutdown.html : When the real shutting down starts after any delays, all filesystems (except the root one) are unmounted

Answer (score 0):

In my interpretation it means you should use `umount` to unmount the partition and `mount` to mount it again since some LiveCDs mount partitions in readonly mode by default.

A manual with more a detailed explanation of the commands of the linked answer can be found here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root